# Unable to uninstall ROS Noetic from Windows 11

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

I had installed ROS Noetic on Windows 11 but eventually decided to dual-boot my laptop with Ubuntu, so I went to uninstall ROS-Noetic from Windows, but am not able to do so because of the following error:

[image: Windows ROS-Noetic Error]

It is still taking up 5.70 GB of storage space. If anyone knows a solution, please help.

I have tried running `rmdir /s /q c:\opt` in the terminal, but I get

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

From other stack overflow posts, it's not uncommon to run into issues using the `rmdir` command for basic operations like this one.

You could try:

- using the absolute path to work around a windows bug ([source](https://superuser.com/a/1739696))
- using the bash shell, or WSL, to delete the file instead of powershell, etc. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41267957))
- compressing the folder so it's an archive and then deleting the archive ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47495038))

Looks like this is a windows issue not a ROS issue, so I'd be searching through information on that.